# ADO.net sybase ASEConnection error

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, sap-ase

sometimes I got the below error when trying to open connection to sybase using ase client

> Connection to Sybase server has been lost. All active transactions
>   have been rolled back Stack Trace :    at
>   Sybase.Data.AseClient1.AseCommand.CheckResult(Int32 res)    at
>   Sybase.Data.AseClient1.AseCommand._ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   commandBehavior)    at
>   Sybase.Data.AseClient.AseCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)    at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet
>   dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords,
>   String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32
>   startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command,
>   CommandBehavior behavior)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet)

I am using dll `Sybase.AdoNet2.AseClient (64 bit) version 2.155.1015.0`

my code is as follows

```
AseConnection Connection = new AseConnection("ConnectionString");
AseCommand Command = new AseCommand("StoredProcedure", Connection);
Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
AseDataAdapter adapter = new AseDataAdapter();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adapter.SelectCommand = Command;
adapter.MissingSchemaAction = SchemaAction;
adapter.Fill(ds);
```

this code run under IIS web service

search does not lead to something useful, what I get is [`this link`](http://nntp-archive.sybase.com/nntp-archive/action/article/%3C448d8ccf@forums-2-dub%3E), but with no help

Comment: How long doe's the query take? it might be a TimeOut issue. `AseCommand.CommandTimeout` to set timeout.

Comment: Another idea to do with commiting transactions, none are one left open are they?

Comment: the called stored takes less than 1 second when run with the same parameters in DBAritisan

Comment: the procedure mainly fill a temp table and then make some calculations and update it, the procedure don't call begin tran or commit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

couldn't find any solution for this defect or the root cause of this, so i developed just catched this exception and then retried the connection and command execution